# Search for value and enter before in doubly linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I'm getting a segmentation fault after I choose this option and type the char I want to add in front of. This is just the function fyi.

struct:

```
struct node
  {
 struct node *previous;
 char data;
 struct node *next;
}*head, *last;
```

function:

```
int before(int value, int loc)
{
 struct node *temp,*var,*temp1;
 var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 var->data=value;
     if(head==NULL)
 {
       head=var;
       head->previous=NULL;
       head->next=NULL;
 }
 else
 {
       temp=head;
       while(temp!=NULL && temp->data!=loc)
       {
             temp=temp->next;
       }
       if(temp==NULL)
       {
            printf("\n%c is not present in list ",loc);
       }
       else
       {
       temp1=temp->next;
       temp->next=var;
       var->previous=temp; 
      var->next=temp1;
       temp1->previous=var;
       }
 }
 last=head;
 while(last->next!=NULL)
 {
       last=last->next;
 }
}
```

I thought NULL would work but it isn't, I just need some clarification to try it on my own.

Would still like some help...

Comment: Do create separate questions for different topics; and do post enough code so we can reproduce your error. What are the values of `value` and `loc` when you call `before`? What prevents a giant memory leak when `before` is called multiple times (and `var` keeps pointing to new memory)? How is `struct node` defined? So many questions...

Comment: Updated, if more is needed let me know :)

Comment: Please see: http://sscce.org/  -- also fixing the indentation would be helpful

Answer (score 4):

In this part of the code:

```
   while(temp!=NULL && temp->data!=loc)
   {
     temp=temp->next;
   }

   if(temp==NULL)
   {
     printf("\n%c is not present in list ",loc);
   }
   else
   {
     temp1=temp->next;
     temp->next=var;
     var->previous=temp; 
     var->next=temp1;
     temp1->previous=var;
   }
```

It is possible that `temp` is not NULL, but `temp->next` is (namely, if `temp` is the last item in the list). Then you get a segmentation fault in the line `temp1->previous = var;`...

**EDIT** since you were still struggling to get this to work, I wrote a complete example. This uses a slightly different structure - I have one function to find out where to insert, and another to do the inserting. I trust you can figure out in what way your code does not go through the same steps that this code does, and that you'll be able to figure it out from here.

I inserted a couple of `printf` statements to confirm that things are behaving as intended - this is usually a good idea during debugging.

I hope this helps!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    struct node *previous;
    char data;
    struct node *next;
}*head, *last; 

struct node * insertBetween(struct node * p1, struct node * p2, char value)
{
    struct node* newItem = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("inserting between %p and %p\n", p1, p2);
    newItem->data = value;
    newItem->next = p2;
    newItem->previous = p1;
    if (p1 == NULL) 
    {
        printf("have a new head!\n");
        head = newItem;
        head->next = p2;
        if (p2 != NULL) p2->previous = head;
        else last = newItem;
    }
    else
    {
        p1->next = newItem;
        p2->previous = newItem;
    }
    printf("insertBetween completed\n");
    return newItem;
}

int before(char value, char loc)
{
    struct node *temp,*var,*temp1, *penultimate=NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        printf("creating head\n");
        head = insertBetween(NULL, NULL, value);
    }
    else
    {
        temp=head;
        while(temp!=NULL && temp->data!=loc)
        {
            printf("data is %c\n", temp->data);
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        if(temp==NULL)
        {
            printf("\n%c is not present in list \n",loc);
        }
        else
        {
        // create a new element
        insertBetween(temp->previous, temp, value);
        }
    }

    // confirming that "last" is still the last element - should not need this:
    // and that the list integrity is intact
    temp=head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("element %p has value %c and points to element %p\n", temp, temp->data, temp->next);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("in the end, temp is %p and last is %p\n", temp, last);
}   

int main(void) {
before('z','a');
before('y','z');
before('x','y');
before('X','y');
before('2', 'z');
printf("inserted everything!\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what to do and where to begin fixing the code. Even if temp is not NULL I'm still confused as to what to change it to.

Comment: @Hamas4 - I have written a complete working code example. I hope this clears up your confusion about working with linked lists.